# How to fetch data from google groups using Rest API?

Tags: rest, google-groups, google-groups-api

I am trying to fetch data from Google Groups using Rest API, but I am not able to do so. I used Admin SDK API for this and am getting this error.
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4xfb.png)
Can someone please tell me why this error is coming and what to do to solve this error.